# How to use one-time binding with callback response in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, databinding

Based on [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm) we know that there are 2 types of binding:

`{!v.parentAttr}` and `{#v.parentAttr}`

As we know, one time binding (`{#...}`) does not set up event listeners for change of attribute so this is more efficient. In my components I use Object field labels that I get from Apex and bind using two-way binding.

```
<aura:attribute name="labels" type="String[]"/>
```

Usage as table headers:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.labels}" var="label">
    <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-truncate">
        <div title="{!label}">{!label}</div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:iteration>
```

And I retrieve labels with controller:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    if (response.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
        component.set("v.labels", response.getReturnValue());
    }
});
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getLabels() {
    return new List<String>{
        MyObject__c.MyField1__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
        MyObject__c.MyField2__c.getDescribe().getLabel(),
        // ...
    };
}
```

I want to use one-time binding for this. One of possible options I see is to create a wrapper component, where I would retrieve labels and in callback dynamically create child component with one-time binding.

Is this the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a callback handler to update an unbound variable, because the other elements won't realize that anything's happened. The same article you quoted states:

> Don’t use a component’s init event and client-side controller to
>   initialize an attribute that is used in an unbound expression. The
>   attribute will not be initialized. Use a bound expression instead. For
>   more information on a component’s init event, see Invoking Actions on
>   Component Initialization.

Unbound data expressions are primarily useful for binding to a default value (aura:attribute default=...) or using configuration values that are preconfigured (such as using a design token).

Since you need the update to be detected, you'll need a normal data binding.